# Focus behaviour in textArea in cn1

Tags: codenameone

I have a textArea which works alright. I've a minor issue here. As soon as there is focus in the textArea, there is no text cursor blinking. It seems like the app hangs here. I've to touch the outside of the textArea and click it again to make it work. And when the other component is touched the keypad stays as before. In the second try only does the textArea has blinking text cursor.

Have a look at the video [here.](https://youtu.be/Qfdv8YtDqU4)

```
public Booking(Resources res) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    mainContainer.setScrollableY(true);

    Label datePickerIconLabel = new Label(addIcon);

    Picker datePicker = new Picker();
    datePicker.setUIID("small");
    datePicker.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);
    Container datePickerContainer = BoxLayout.encloseX(datePickerIconLabel, datePicker);
    mainContainer.add(datePickerContainer);

    TextArea remarksArea = new TextArea();
    remarksArea.setUIID("TextField");
    remarksArea.setConstraint(TextField.NON_PREDICTIVE);
    remarksArea.setRows(4);
    remarksArea.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.TOP);
    remarksArea.setHint("  Remarks");
    remarksArea.getHintLabel().setUIID("TextField");
    remarksArea.getAllStyles().setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    remarksArea.getHintLabel().getAllStyles().setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    mainContainer.add(remarksArea);

    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainContainer);
 }
```

Comment: What's the specific OS/device combination?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the "no blinking cursor" issue. Can you confirm that typing into the text area still works for you even when the cursor isn't blinking?  (that's what I'm getting .. textarea still works - just no blinking cursor)

Comment: yeahhh text area still works. Just the cursor isn't blinking which is making the users get confused and they complain the app is not working

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I've checked in android devices like samsung and few other brands with same issue in all of them

Comment: Can you please file an issue? We already have a similar issue with the cursor disappearing so I'm guessing there is some work to address these two together https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2317

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2353

Comment: Its still not solved. The text cursor starts to appear if only the keyboard is already opened other wise it does not appear.